# Kendo UI Mobile forcing empty cell to not display in template

Tags: kendo-mobile

Is it possible to force an empty cell to not display in a template?

Currently my template is:

```
template = kendo.template("#if (title != null){#<span class=\"box favorable\">50</span><div class=\"title\">${ title }</div>#}else{}#");
```

However, if the `else` statement is called, it just displays an empty cell.  I want the cell to not be displayed, instead of being an empty cell.

Comment: are you referring to a table cell which is outside your template?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the table in the template to have a total control over it. For example, in your case, you need an approach like this:

```
template = kendo.template("
  <table>
    # for (var i=0; i<rows.length;i++) { #
      #if (title != null){#
        <tr><td>
          <span class=\"box favorable\">50</span><div class=\"title\">#= title #</div>
        </td></tr>
      #}#
    # } #
  </table>
");
```

Comment: This is Kendo UI Mobile.  The listview cells are `li` elements, not table cells.

Comment: I see. So this is a question about the KendoUI Mobile Listview gadget rather than KendoUI templating. Whatever you put in the template, the widget will automatically wrap it in <li> tag. The unwanted items should be removed from the ListView data source before the ListView is rendered.

Comment: Got it.  The entire datasource method is very inefficient, but I guess I have no choice.